# How to join tables on a partly-overlapping key column while retaining all data and not creating duplicate columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables that all have a “date” column and another column with counts of different variables - let’s call the tables T1, T2, and T3 and each of their columns  are counts of dogs, cats, and birds spotted that day.

Not every table has the same set of dates. Example:

T1: Dogs spotted by day

```
date       | dogs
------------------
2020-08-26 | 1
2020-08-27 | 4
```

T2: Cats spotted by day

```
date         | cats
---------------------
2020-08-25   | 2
2020-08-26   | 5
```

T3: Cats spotted by day

```
date         | birds
---------------------
2020-08-26   | 8
2020-08-27   | 3
2020-08-28   | 5
```

I’m trying to join them together on date while keeping all column data, but I’m having trouble doing so without getting a table that has 3 date columns. There’s no table that has all of the dates, so if I just select one of the date columns (e.g. `select t1.date, t1.dogs, t2.cats, t3.birds`) then I lose some of the date data. What I’m seeking is a table like this:

Desired Output: All Animals Spotted by Day

```
date         | dogs         | cats        | birds       |
----------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-25   | 0 (or null)  | 2           | 0 (or null) |   
2020-08-26   | 1            | 5           | 8           |   
2020-08-27   | 4            | 0 (or null) | 3           |   
2020-08-28   | 0 (or null)  | 0 (or null) | 5           |
```

I’ve read about every stack overflow post on this I could find but maybe I’m not putting in the correct keywords because I’m not finding this. I’m working specifically in Postgres. Thank you!!

Comment: I've seen other people create another table with just dates (every day from start to finish), where end date is maybe in 2049 or whenever you think the world will end. Then you select from that table and left join the other 3. Query may look like select d.date, coalesce(t1.dogs, 0) as dogs, coalesce(t2.cats, 0) as cats,  etc.

Comment: Do you only want the query via joins ?

Comment: You might want to re-think your data model. A single table with `animal, date, sightings` would be a better way to store this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_series` to construct a table of dates and use outer joins with the other tables:

```
SELECT d.d::date,
       t1.dogs,
       t2.cats,
       t3.birds
FROM generate_series ('2020-08-25'::timestamp, '2020-08-28'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) AS d(d)
   LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.date = d.d::date
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.dat3 = d.d::date
   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.date = d.d::date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of knowing the design why you need or you could change it further,

Using `union` and `aggregation` could be one option,

```
select date
     , max(dogs) as dogs
     , max(cats) as cats
     , max(birds) as birds
from
(
 select date,dogs,0 cats,0 birds from t1
 union all
 select date,0,cats,0 from t2
 union all
 select date,0,0,birds from t3
) t
group by date
order by date;
```

***Note: Don't know if multiple entry possible for a single date , in case yes you need to use `sum` instead `max`***

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `full join`.  For your example `select *` does what you want:

```
select *
from cats c full join
     dogs d
     using (date) full join
     birds b
     using (date);
```

I might recommend, however, that you put all the counts into a single table, with an additional column specifying "cat", "dog" and so on.  If you had that, then simple aggregation would work:

```
select date,
       count(*) filter (where type = 'cat'),
       count(*) filter (where type = 'dog'),
       count(*) filter (where type = 'bird')
from t
group by date;
```